# Magento set quantity in shopping cart -> quantity not available

Tags: magento

I use Magento 1.5.1 to power a fashion webshop. I noticed a strange behaviour from Magento which I hope you can help me resolve:

Here is the scenario:

1. An item has 5 pieces in stock.
2. A user adds 5 to its cart
3. In the mean time someone has bought 1 item so 5 is not available any more. New stock is 4. In my opinion the user should be able to reset the qty to 4.
4. The user tries to reset the qty to 4. That, however,does not work. All I get at this stage is that the qty is not available and the quantity stays at 5.

EDIT: 
To clarify step 4 a little bit more:
I receive a message that the item is out of stock once I try to set the qty to 4.

Is this a known Magento bug? How can I check what is causing this?

Thanks

Comment: I didn't unserstand step 4, could you please explain little bit more? what happened if they change the product quantity from 5 to 4? Are there any message?

Comment: @Oguz, Thanks for the response. See edit above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oke, finally found a workaround:

\app\code\core\mage\checkout\model\cart.php Line 383 - 386

change:

```
$item->setQty($qty);
if ($item->getHasError()) {
  Mage::throwException($item->getMessage());
}
```

to:

```
$oldqty = $item->getQty();
$item->setQty($qty);
if ($item->getHasError() && $qty > $oldqty) {
  Mage::throwException($item->getMessage());
}
```

Now it checks if the new qty is lower then the old qty. If so, continue. Otherwise do the old behaviour.